# Newrelic developermode not working with ruby-prof

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic, ruby-prof

I'm using the `newrelic_rpm` developer mode locally in a rails 3.2 app. This is working fine.

When I install `ruby-prof` and click "start profiling" in the newrelic local dashboard and go back to my app, every page in my app gives "undefined method `pop' for #.

The top few lines of the traceback:

```
newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:421:in `ensure in perform_action_with_newrelic_profile'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:421:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_profile'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:305:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:37:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
```

Any ideas how to work out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's been a while, but we've fixed the issue that was preventing ruby-prof from working in developer mode previously, so you should now be able to use it again with recent versions of the agent (3.7.3 and later). I'll get that known issues page updated also.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm switching this to the approved answer, as 3.5.8.72 is (I believe) a bit out of date for using with newrelic on the server

Answer (score 8):

Dropped back to version `3.5.8.72` and it worked again. Just update your Gemfile with `gem "newrelic_rpm", "3.5.8.72"`. I've logged an issue with them on it.

Comment: fantastic, thanks. Didn't realize this was a regression. can you share the issue url (for me and others).

Comment: It's behind zendesk, so not sure if it's a private ticket: https://support.newrelic.com/requests/45254 - Unfortunately the news isn't great: "Unfortunately, this is a known issue with version 3.6.x, and we're unlikely to push a fix any time soon."

Comment: thanks. It is a private ticket. They said they will update the known issues page with this until it is fixed.

Comment: Documented at https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/developer-mode#known_issues "ruby-prof for Ruby 3.5.8.72"